# Enum.Parse(), surely a neater way?

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

Say I have an enum,

```
public enum Colours
{
    Red,
    Blue
}
```

The only way I can see of parsing them is doing something like:

```
string colour = "Green";
var col = (Colours)Enum.Parse(typeOf(Colours),colour);
```

This will throw a [System.ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx) because "Green" is not a member of the `Colours` enum.

Now I really hate wrapping code in try/catch's, is there no neater way to do this that doesn't involve me iterating through each `Colours` enum, and doing a string comparison against `colour`?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use [`Enum.IsDefined()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx) first, to save yourself from wrapping in a try/catch. It will return a boolean value of whether or not the input is a valid member of that enum.

Comment: What's more remember that numbers in string will be parsed even if not in your Enum! So remember to TryParse and check if IsDefined to catch that quirk!

Answer (score 42):

I believe that 4.0 has **[Enum.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.tryparse%28VS.100%29.aspx)**

Otherwise use an [extension method](http://www.objectreference.net/post/Enum-TryParse-Extension-Method.aspx):

```
public static bool TryParse<T>(this Enum theEnum, string valueToParse, out T returnValue)
{
    returnValue = default(T);
    int intEnumValue;
    if (Int32.TryParse(valueToParse, out intEnumValue))
    {
        if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), intEnumValue))
        {
            returnValue = (T)(object)intEnumValue;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This TryParse is different to 4.0 TryParse, valueToParse must be a (string)((byte)YourEnum.YourValue)), the source uses it to parse enum number from url query string, you can not use it to parse (string)YourEnum.YourValue

Comment: this custom method `public static bool TryParse<T>(this Enum theEnum, string valueToParse, out T returnValue)` requires generic parameter constraint to be added `public static bool TryParse<T>(this Enum theEnum, string valueToParse, out T returnValue) where T : struct` e.g.

Answer (score 9):

Just to expand on Sky's link to the [.Net 4 Enum.TryParse<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), viz

```
Enum.TryParse<TEnum>(
    string value,
    [bool ignoreCase,]
    out TEnum result
)
```

This can be used as follows:

```
    enum Colour
    {
        Red,
        Blue
    }

    private void ParseColours()
    {
        Colour aColour;

        // IMO using the actual enum type is intuitive, but Resharper gives 
        // "Access to a static member of a type via a derived type"
        if (Colour.TryParse("RED", true, out aColour))
        {
           // ... success
        }

        // OR, the compiler can infer the type from the out
        if (Enum.TryParse("Red", out aColour))
        {
           // ... success
        }

        // OR explicit type specification
        // (Resharper: Type argument specification is redundant)
        if (Enum.TryParse<Colour>("Red", out aColour))
        {
          // ... success
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

No, there's no "no-throw" method for this (a la TryParse that some other classes have).

However, you could easily write your own so as to encapsulate the try-catch logic (or the IsDefined check) in one helper method so it doesn't pollute your app code:

```
public static object TryParse(Type enumType, string value, out bool success)
{
  success = Enum.IsDefined(enumType, value);
  if (success)
  {
    return Enum.Parse(enumType, value);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If I'm parsing a "*trusted*" enum, then I use Enum.Parse().
By "*trusted*" I mean, I know it will ALWAYS be a valid enum without ever erroring... ever!

But there are times when "*you never know what you're gonna get*", and for those times, you need to use a nullable return value.  Since .net doesn't offer this baked in, you can roll your own.  Here's my recipe:

```
public static TEnum? ParseEnum<TEnum>(string sEnumValue) where TEnum : struct
{
    TEnum eTemp;
    TEnum? eReturn = null;
    if (Enum.TryParse<TEnum>(sEnumValue, out eTemp) == true)
        eReturn = eTemp;
    return eReturn;
}
```

To use this method, call it like so:

```
eColor? SelectedColor = ParseEnum<eColor>("Red");
```

Just add this method to a class you use to store your other commonly used utility functions.