# Has anyone got a copy of the Enumeration Parser class ("Stop the Madness")

Tags: c#, enums, mirror

Code from http://www.monstersgotmy.net/post/Enumerations-and-Strings-Stop-the-Madness!.aspx
is mentioned in a number of questions about parsing Enums in C#.

Has anyone got a copy of this code? The original site seems to have disappeared.

Comment: Can you explain what the code is for?

Comment: I found references to this when I was looking for an example of how to generically convert between System.Enum and custom Enums.

I believe it was some code to avoid the extra cast in
        


   Enumerations.MyCustomEnum aValue (Enumerations.MyCustomEnum) Enum.Parse(typeof(Enumerations.MyCustomEnum),myValue);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394725/enum-parse-surely-a-neater-way

This question is what I was trying to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw that my original link to this article is now a link farm, so I took what I had out of our codebase (modified over time) and put it on Gist. It's pretty much what was in the article, but cleaned up and with a few additional extension methods.

https://gist.github.com/1305566

Comment: Wow! I'd forgotten about this question. Thanks.