# Get matching enum int values from list of strings

Tags: c#, enums

I have a enum of colors with different int values

```
enum Colors { Red = 1, Blue = 2, Green = 5, Yellow = 7, Pink = 10, Black = 15 };
```

and I have a list of strings that contains color names (I can suppose that all the names in the list exists in the enum).

I need to create a list of ints of all the colors in the list of strings.
For example - for the list `{"Blue", "red", "Yellow"}` I want to create a list - `{2, 1, 7}`.
I don't care about the order.

My code is the code below. I use a dictionary and foreach-loop. Can I do it with linq and make my code shorter and simpler?

```
public enum Colors { Red = 1, Blue = 2, Green = 5, Yellow = 7, Pink = 10, Black = 15 };

public List<int> getColorInts(List<string> myColors)
{
    // myColors contains strings like "Red", "Blue"..

    List<int> colorInts = new List<int>();
    foreach (string color in myColors)
    {
         Colors result;
         bool success = Enum.TryParse(color , out result);
         if (success)
         {
             colorInts .Add((int)result);
         }
    }
    return colorInts;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [Enum.TryParse ?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15239599/314291). Once you have the Enum, you can just cast it back to int if that's what you want.

Comment: It helps me to remove the dictionary from my code, but it does not replace my foreach-loop. I'll edit my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var res = colorList.Select(x => (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(Colors), x, true)).ToList();
```

You can use [Enum.Parse(Type, String, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. But it **will throw exception** if **not found the value** in Enum. 
In such situation you can filter the array firstly with the help of `IsDefined` method.

```
 var res = colorList.Where(x=> Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Colors), x))
                    .Select(x => (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(Colors), x, true)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Just project each string to appropriate enum value (of course make sure strings are valid enum names):

```
myColors.Select(s => (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(Colors), s, ignoreCase:true))
```

Result:

```
2, 1, 7
```

If it is possible to have string which is not name of enum member, then you should use your approach with dictionary or use `Enum.TryParse` to check if name is valid:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetColorsValues(IEnumerable<string> colors)
{
    Colors value;
    foreach (string color in colors)
        if (Enum.TryParse<Colors>(color, true, out value))
            yield return (int)value;
}
```

Comment: @TamarG you are welcome, I also added option with parsing strings which are not enum names

Answer (score 2):

Use `Enum.Parse` and cast it to int.

```
public List<int> GetColorInts(IEnumerable<string> myColors)
{
    return myColors
        .Select(x => Enum.Parse(typeof(Colors), x, true))
        .Cast<int>()
        .ToList();
}
```

I've used third parameter of `Enum.Parse` to true to make the Parsing case insensitive. You could make it case sensitive by just passing false or completely ignoring the argument.